# How can I execute arbitrary function in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm new to iOS development. I don't know all of keyboard shortcut for Xcode.

- In Android Studio, press shift key twice
- In Visual Studio Code, Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+P

These are shortcut for list all feature of IDE. I can select from it to run arbitrary function of IDE.

Is there any shortcut for this feature in Xcode?

Comment: Sorry, I edited question. It don't mean to execute a function of my code. I want to call a feature of IDE such as "open settings", "build", "enter fullscreen" etc.

Comment: [Xcode Preferences ⌘, → Key Bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mohV4.jpg). Note that on macOS, you naturally get the corresponding shortcut from the menu itself in any application.